# How many bricks can be put without disordering the equilibrium?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statics, equilibrium

A homogenous brick with length L, is on a horizontal surface. On this brick are put one after another other bricks, which are the same with the first. Every brick is moved along L/5 units horizontally from the predecessor one. How many bricks can be put without disordering the equilibrium?

My idea. I can just draw this figure: 
[image]

Then I can say that we know that the center of G should fall on the base of the brick.But I don't know how many bricks can be put.

Comment: A very nice follow up question is how many bricks can be put maximally if you are free in the size of your shift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You idea is exactly right. With that diagram, you need to figure out where the center of gravity is.

The position of the center of gravity is a direct function of the number of bricks. In general, when you have $n$ bricks with equal offsets, the center of gravity is exactly midway between bricks $1$ and $n$ (by symmetry). The first brick is in contact with the ground, and it will not fall over. We need to worry about bricks #2 through n in this case - their center of gravity is the one that will determine if the stack will fall.

If we put the center of brick $1$ at x = 0, and the position of brick $n$ is

$$x_n = (n-1)\frac{L}{5}$$

Then the center of gravity is midway between the center of brick 2 and the center of brick n.

$$G = \frac{x_2+x_n}{2} = (1 + n - 1)\frac{L}{10}$$

The tower will fall over when $G > \frac{L}{2}$. It follows that $n > 5$. A stack of six brick will fall over.

Comment: How did you get the second equation? And how did you go to the conclusion that n=6?

Comment: @AnnalianLoverre - I have updated my answer to clarify that a little more. My initial answer was not quite correct.